# Android Development: "Cannot be resolved"

Tags: java, android

Hoping to get into android app development so I'm doing some basic tutorials just now.

Just trying to get comfortable with the basics at the moment, one of which is using the Typeface class.

```
package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    private View mainView;
    private TextView tbox1;
    private Button exitButton;
    @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mainView=(View)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
    mainView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));

    tbox1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
    tbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
}
}
```

The line

```
tbox1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
```

Has a red cross beside it (I'm using eclipse) with the error

```
tbox1 cannot be resolved
```

Its been a while since i have used java, but as i aware the following code

1. create a new TextView object called tbox1
2. Assigns the tbox1 object the id specified in the xml for the TextView tag in an external main.xml
3. Then tbox1 executes the setTypeFace() method on itself?

Obviously I'm going wrong somewhere, any ideas? Something really simple no doubt...

Comment: did you declare a textview with id textBox1 inside your layout?

Comment: Yes,  <TextView
     android:textColor="#FF0000"
     android:id="@+id/textBox1"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
     android:gravity="center"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:text="@string/salutation"
    />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't inform us about one error and neglect the others. Look at your code.

Besides what user370305 said, you have *other* problems. Namely, your `Activity`, according to the contract, `implements OnClickListener` but does not override the necessary `onClick(View v)` method. You must add it for the contract to be met.

So your code should look like:

```
package org.me.myandroidstuff;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private View mainView;

    private TextView tbox1;

    private Button exitButton;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mainView=(View)findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        mainView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.silver));

        tbox1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
        tbox1.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Remember, you can't talk about errors until you fix every other that might cause other errors to be falsely reported.

Comment: Sorry, the code was ok and didn't have any errors (that i caused by removing lines of code before posting on here). I removed alot of the code before posting to try and highlight the offending errors. In any case its working now. So thanks all for the feedback.

Comment: @cosmicsafari the important thing is that you resolved it :) happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

First try to set setContentView(R.layout.yourlayoutfilename); in onCreate().

Answer (score 0):

1.) Delete line super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

2.) Retype super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

3.) Clean the Project

4.) Build the Project